# classic asp loop function

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

The following code is to add the font tag to every character, but it don't work

```
Function AddFontTag (counter)
    Do While Len (counter) < 7
        newStr = newStr & "<font>" & Left (counter, i) & "</font>"
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    AddFontTag = newStr
End Function
```

Because i'm not skilled in classic asp, such as variable scope, syntax. Does anyone know what's the problems of the above code?

thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do with this function? If you update your question with an output example (what you expect the function to output) it may be possible to give you a better answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `do..while` loop is an infinite loop - assuming `counter` is a string variable, its length never changes so if `Len(counter)` is less than `7` upon entering the function, it'll always stay less than `7` so your function never exits.

Your `newStr` variable is undefined - this works in VBScript but it's really bad practice and it's a source of countless errors. Is it a global variable or is it supposed to be a local? (It looks like a local.)

Comment: thanks, i've solved: Function AddFontTag (counter)
 For i = 1 to 7 
  newStr = newStr & "<font>" & mid(counter,i,1) & "</font>"
 Next
 AddFontTag = newStr
End Function

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of how your 7 character limit applies, but for a general approach the following will do what you need for any length string:

```vb
function AddFontTag(byval str)
    AddFontTag = Empty
    do while len(str) <> 0
        ' get next character
        dim c: c = left(str, 1)
        ' reduce original string
        str = right(str, len(str) - 1)
        ' build up output string
        AddFontTag = AddFontTag & "<font>" & c & "</font>"
    loop
end function
```

The example

```
dim test: test = AddFontTag("a test")
Response.Write test
```

will give you

> <font>a</font><font> </font><font>t</font><font>e</font><font>s</font><font>t</font>

If you only want to apply this to strings of length less than 7 you can add

```
if len(str) > 6 then
    exit function
end if
```

before the while loop or

```
str = left(str, 6)
```

if you just want to apply it to the first 6 characters of any length string

Answer (score 0):

your codes is looping without a condition to EXIT the looping.
try this... hope it helps.

```
Function AddFontTag (counter)
dim i,newStr,max
max=7
    Do While Len (counter) < max
        newStr = newStr & "<font>" & Left (counter, i) & "-" & "</font>"
        i = i + 1
        if i = max-1 then exit Do
    Loop
    AddFontTag = newStr
End Function
'to check the results
response.write AddFontTag ("params")
```

you will get
      `<font>-</font><font>p-</font><font>pa-</font><font>par-</font><font>para-</font><font>param-</font>`